# Image.loadFromFile() doesn't work?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I've been looking around in my code for hours now and finally I think I found the issue with the code. An SFML method doesn't work or I am using it wrong.

I am trying to load a PNG file from my disk into the program so I can render it on screen.

But the picture is never even loaded into the program to begin with it seems. As when I check the debugger I see no actual info about the file I am trying to load in.

I'll show the entire Engine.cpp file first, and then explain step by step what happens.

My Engine.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "Engine.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

Engine::Engine()
{

}

Engine::~Engine()
{

}

bool Engine::Init()
{
    LoadImages();
    window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32), "RPG");
    if(!window)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void Engine::LoadImages()
{
    sf::Image sprite;
    sprite.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Vipar/Pictures/sprite1.png");
    imageManager.AddImage(sprite);
    testTile = new Tile(imageManager.GetImage(0));
}

void Engine::RenderFrame()
{
    window->clear();
    testTile->Draw(0,0,window);
    window->display();
}

void Engine::ProcessInput()
{
    sf::Event evt;
    //Loop through all window events
    while(window->pollEvent(evt))
    {
        if(evt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window->close();
    }
}

void Engine::Update()
{

}

void Engine::MainLoop()
{
    sf::Image sprite;
    sprite.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Vipar/Pictures/sprite1.png");
    imageManager.AddImage(sprite);
    testTile = new Tile(imageManager.GetImage(0));

    //Loop until our window is closed
    while(window->isOpen())
    {
        ProcessInput();
        Update();
        RenderFrame();
        testTile->Draw(0,0,window);
    }
}

void Engine::Go()
{
    if(!Init())
        throw "Could not initialize Engine";
    MainLoop();
}
```

I call this method:

```
void Engine::LoadImages()
{
    sf::Image sprite;
    sprite.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Vipar/Pictures/sprite1.png");
    imageManager.AddImage(sprite);
    testTile = new Tile(imageManager.GetImage(0));
}
```

It adds the Image to my ImageManager for later use if need be. This is done for a bit of efficiency. Then I apply the Image to my custom class called `Tile`. It looks like this:

```
#include "Tile.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

Tile::Tile(sf::Image& image)
{
    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromImage(image);
    baseSprite.setTexture(tex,true);
}

Tile::~Tile()
{

}

void Tile::Draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow* rw)
{
    baseSprite.setPosition(x,y);
    rw->draw(baseSprite);
}

void Tile::Destroy()
{
    delete &baseSprite;
}
```

Then I draw the Tile on screen to test it out.

Why does this png file not even load into my program to begin with? If you need additional code, please let me know. I am a bit green on this SFML framework and C++ but I am good at Java and C#.

Comment: Are you using SFML 2.0 ? If so the class to use for image loading and displaying is sf::Texture (in combination with sf::Sprite), not sf::Image. Also could you show how you are storing your images ? Do you have any error printed in the console ? Edit : I remember some time ago SFML had difficulties to load non 8bit pngs, check that too.

Comment: Yeah I found out that the picture for some reason was not 8-bit. Don't know why. I used another picture and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I only work with SFML.net (maybe you should use it?), and I don't like how you're doing things, but...

- Throw some debug messages to make sure that all your appropriate
  functions/code is getting run.
- Clear with a different color and make sure it works.
- Your naming is confusing and misleading.
- Make sure you've checked the tutorial to see how they draw.